# Can I play audio in reverse by writing AMR data bytes in reverse order?

Tags: java, android, audio

I record audio and then read it with CheapAMR.java. That class has a write function which writes the bytes of the read file in a new file. Is it possible to change the for loop to write the bytes backwards so when I play the new file it actually plays backwards?

```
public void WriteFile(File outputFile, int startFrame, int numFrames)
        throws java.io.IOException {
    outputFile.createNewFile();
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(mInputFile);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

    byte[] header = new byte[6];
    header[0] = '#';
    header[1] = '!';
    header[2] = 'A';
    header[3] = 'M';
    header[4] = 'R';
    header[5] = '\n';
    out.write(header, 0, 6);

    int maxFrameLen = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
        if (mFrameLens[startFrame + i] > maxFrameLen)
            maxFrameLen = mFrameLens[startFrame + i];
    }
    byte[] buffer = new byte[maxFrameLen];
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
        int skip = mFrameOffsets[startFrame + i] - pos;
        int len = mFrameLens[startFrame + i];
        if (skip < 0) {
            continue;
        }
        if (skip > 0) {
            in.skip(skip);
            pos += skip;
        }
        in.read(buffer, 0, len);
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        pos += len;
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: I guess instead of typing a question and waiting for an answer, you could have tried it simply by doing it and maybe failing. :P

Comment: @MrPixelDream - no, because an experimental result is far less definitive than one based on an understanding of what is going on.  With an experimental result, you don't know if you accomplished the substance of what you meant to, or if you made a trivial mistake, such as corrupting a header in a format where (unlike the AMR at issue here) the payload data actually is trivially reversible.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You should have tried before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because AMR is a compressed format - you would have to actually interpret the data in order to recompress it in reverse order.

If you instead had a simple format such as a linear-PCM .wav file, you could reverse it by re-ordering the samples.  But you'd need to be careful to skip over the headers and any embedded meta-data.  And you'd want to not reverse the *bytes* but rather the *samples* - typically (but not always) that would mean reading a 16 bit sample for each of left and right (32 bits overall) and reversing that as a unit.  If you just reversed the bytes after the header, you would not only swap the channels, but get absolutely horrible, at most remotely intelligble sound as a result of swapping the high and low bytes of typically 16-bit audio samples.